# NameError at /?

Tags: python, django

Я еще новичок в сфере программирования и не могу понять, почему он не видит мою глобальную переменную `user`.

```
def authoriz(request):
    log = request.POST.get('login')
    pas = request.POST.get('password')
    print(log, '       ', pas)
    auth_f = False
    if log is not None:
        try:
            global user
            user = users.objects.get(login = log, password = pas)
            sl = 'Успешная авторизация. Пройдите в главное меню'
            auth_f = True
        except:
            sl = 'Неверный логин или пароль'
    else:
        sl = ' '

    return render(request, 'auth.html', {'auth_f': auth_f, 'succ_auth': sl})
```

А вот здесь выдает ошибку "NameError at /jour/ name 'user' is not defined":

```
def read_jour(request):
    tr_op = user.trade_set.all()
    return render(request, 'jour.html', {'trade_op': tr_op})
```

Comment: 1) Глобальная переменная должна быть объявлена вне любых классов/функций, тогда с оператором `global ` эту переменную можно менять, иначе вместо этого в текущей области видимости просто создастся переменная с таким же названием 2) Глобальные переменные по юзеру для сервера плохая идея, если только он один не будет им пользоваться :)

Answer (score 0):

Может у тебя except срабатывает и user просто не существует. Попробуй в функцию read_jour добавить проверку на существование user, чтобы ошибки не было